# How do I combine/group string values of the same key within an array of objects

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of objects like:

```
arr = [{"apple":"sour"}, {"pear":"sweet"}, {"apple":"red"}]
```

Since arr[0] and arr[2] have the same key, what can I do to combine them separated by a space to form something like:

```
[{"apple":"sour red"},{"pear":"sweet"}]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{"apple":"sour"}, {"pear":"sweet"}, {"apple":"red"}]

// create object
const obj = {}
// iterate through the array
for (const item of arr) {
  // get the key e.g. apple
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0]
  // get the value e.g. sour
  const value = item[key]
  if (!(key in obj)) {
    // create an array for each key
    obj[key] = []
  }
  // push value to the key
  obj[key].push(value)
}

// map object to final array
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value.join(' ') }))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to use `reduce` to do it

```js
const arr = [{"apple":"sour"}, {"pear":"sweet"}, {"apple":"red"}]

let data = arr.reduce((acc,val) =>{
 let key = Object.keys(val)[0]
 let obj = acc.find(a => a[key])
 if(obj){
  obj[key] = obj[key] +" " + val[key]
 }else{
  acc.push(val)
 }
 return acc
},[])

console.log(data)
```